# Stopping a program from exiting after completion

Tags: windows, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and trying to set it up on a windows machine. I get it to compile but when I run the .exe file, the program runs and exits right away, barely showing the output.

Below is the sample code I created

```
module Main where
m = 2 * n
n = f 4

--functions
f::Int -> Int
f x = 2 * x

g::Int -> Int -> Int
g x y = 2 * x * y

main = do
x <-getChar --used to pause program

print m
print $ f m
print $ g m n
```

I used the getChar to pause the program until a key is pressed. I've been trying to figure out how to do something like exit on a key stroke after the print statements. How can I do this and could there be a  better way?

Comment: How are you running the program? That seems likely to be the real issue.

Comment: For simple programs like this, you should just run them in ghci. This will fix your problem. However, you can "pause" with `getChar` at the end of the function as well - if you aren't able to get it to work, include the exact code you are running.

Comment: The code I was running is exactly the same as above but I was moving x<- getChar to different location to see the effect. The user below cleared up my problem but thanks for the feedback anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run your program in Windows by clicking on it, then it gets a terminal window of its own which itself exits once the program does. I guess that's what you did, or similar.

But if you instead start a terminal window with a DOS prompt, and run the program from there, then that window will survive after the program ends and you can see your output.

You could also run the program from inside GHCi or WinGHCi with the `:main` command.

Lastly, your `x <- getChar` could *almost* work at the end of `main`, but there's a rule that the last statement in a `do` block must be an expression, so it cannot bind a variable.  But you are not using `x` for anything, so you can just remove the `x <-` part:

```
main = do
    print m
    print $ f m
    print $ g m n
    getChar --used to pause program
```